# Can not receiver android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED

Tags: android, push, broadcastreceiver, wap

I want to receive the WAP Push Message. My code is post as follow:

```
public class PushMsgReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public final static String TAG = "Push Receiver";

private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
private static final String PUSH_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction()); 

    if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
        //toast to show result
        Log.i(TAG, "SMS: " + intent.getAction());
        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS_RECEIVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
    if (intent.getAction().equals(PUSH_RECEIVED)) { 
        //toast to show result
        Log.i(TAG, "PUSH: " + intent.getAction());
        Toast.makeText(context, "PUSH MSG", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

The manifest is post as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.test.pushmsg"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".PushMsgReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
      <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
     </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

It can receive the SMS_RECEIVED,but can not receive the WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED. So Who knows why? I have try to use registerReceiver(),but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Neither `SMS_RECEIVED` nor `WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED` are part of the Android SDK.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the receiver and add data mime part.

```
<receiver android:name=".IncomingMMS" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="net.everythingandroid.smspopup.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.mms.transaction.MESSAGE_SENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.

The `android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED` intent was set an `MIME` type before send.

So
adding the `MIME` type in manifest will works.